# How to debug code running from terminal in pycharm

Tags: debugging, pycharm, attach-to-process

I am running my code in `Pycharm` from Terminal. Is it possible to debug the code and put breakpoints inside the code during a run from terminal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know anyway to do this through the terminal, but the way I currently do it is:

1. `Run` > `Edit Configurations` > Add new configuration (the green `+` button)
2. Choose `Python`
3. Fill out `Script path`, `Parameters`, and other configuration fields.
4. Debug the newly added configuration. (`Run` > `Debug...`)

With the right configuration the result should be the same as running the script in a terminal.

I find the above process a little tedious. A [PEP 553](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553) `breakpoint()` might be nicer. It requires Python 3.7 and is not implemented yet. [See the related issue.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27910)

Answer (score 13):

Even if the program is started outside of PyCharm, we can attach PyCharm debugger to it.

Go to `Run` -> `Attach to process`.

[image]

This will show a list of python process that are currently running on the system. Select the appropriate process from it.

[image]

Now PyCharm debugger is connected to that process. We can add breakpoints and debug it.

Comment: The terminal runs fast and gives error in my case so not sure how to attach a process in between that time. Before and after starting attach options shows no process. Do I need to put a sleep in between?

Comment: @BlueClouds Yes you can add sleep in between if your process is closing before you could attach.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer because the currently accepted answer is about running debug mode in Pycharm which can be found in tons of manuals

Answer (score 5):

There is a way using `python console`.

To run it: `Tools` -> `python console` .. or you can find it at the bottom of the IDE.

Then press on 'Attach debugger' line in the following picture:
[image]

Add a breakpoint in your code and then pass the file name to the cosole, like: `%run my_file.py`